# GameCenter No Events Called

Tags: ios, event-handling, game-center

I am developing a GKTurnBasedGame on iOS. I am having a problem, that when another player is calling endTurnWithNextParticipants, The following function wont get called on the other simulator:

```
func player(player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventForMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool)
```

I am using two simulator on different Macs with Game Center Sandbox Accounts.
On the first device, that calls the endTurn function, the current player is the other player that should receive the event.

I think that this might be a sandbox problem?!

Has anybody an idea or similar problems?

Best regards and thanks a lot!

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing on IOS8.3? If so, that event is broken in 8.3; the even handler never fires for the recipient. The bug is fixed in 8.4.

See [endTurnWithNextParticipants doesn't trigger receivedTurnEventForMatch after update to iOS 8.3 and swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568913/endturnwithnextparticipants-doesnt-trigger-receivedturneventformatch-after-upda/29584268#29584268) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the problem. I am testing with iOS 9 now and its not fixed there.