# Apple doesn't trigger Game Center notifications and callbacks (+1 if you have the same issues)

Tags: ios, callback, push-notification, ios9, game-center

I have a game in development phase and it seems that Apple's Game Center stuff doesn't work correctly. It doesn't trigger game invitations with Push Notification and also the turn based callbacks inside the app are never fired.

This callback:

```
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player receivedTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match didBecomeActive:(BOOL)didBecomeActive
```

is never called right now. Some weeks ago I receveid callbacks inside this method. But from a while nothing.

Is anybody else encountering these kind of issues with Game Center?

So I'm testing on devices, I also freshly reset the devices, of course I'm using `[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] registerListener:self]`, I created a new sample app from scratch  with a different bundleID. But nothing, the same issues from Apple!

Comment: Might just be the usual game center glitches. Take a look at bullet 5 of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31980209/1641444 for how I handle it when turn-based events stop coming through.

Comment: You have a very good and safe approach in your link (+1 from me). But I had already implemented something similar. My biggest concern is regarding the game invitations. The other player should open the Game Center always to see if he has a Game Invite. Obviously, this is not the right approach. Also a manually refresh when you have more simultaneous online games for all of these games may be a kind of inefficient (a hack to cover Apple's issues).

Comment: As I red about these issues, these are only in development phase, so I'm hoping that Apple will have mercy for us and they will provide us a reliable development environment.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen outages with invites and automatching as well. One or both just stop working, sometimes for days. I think it was worse (more frequent) before they consolidated sandbox and production environments, though.